# Laravel treat www as default with wildcard subdomain

Tags: php, laravel

I just setup my sub-domain routing on my server,  added the A record to Route53.

```
*.mysitename.com. A 54.123.123.123
```

My conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mysitename/public"
    ServerName mysitename.com
    ServerAlias mysitename.com *.mysitename.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html/mysitename/public">
        Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My question is how can I get mysitename.com to work, and www.mysitename.com to be treated as mysitename.com rather than processed by my sub-domain route?

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{name}.mysitename.com'), function() {
    Route::get('/', 'ObjectsController@showObject');
});
```

When I goto www.mysite.com it is passing www as a parameter in the ObjectController

```
public function showObject ($name) {
    return Object::whereName($name)->get();
}
```

Comment: Removing Route53/AWS from the question title/tags as they're completely irrelevant to what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Well www is always going to match in the query. Use a conditional statement to check the name doesn't match something. Or, use regexp on the route to filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could strip out the www in apache using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is probably the best option.

Comment: I agree, not too familiar with rewrite rules. What I want is to have www.mydomain.com to redirect to mydomain.com, and any other prefix.mydomain.com to goto the laravel route controller. Is that what that does? Also will that conflict with Laravels default rewrite rules? Thanks a lot, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would create new route that will match only www.mysitename.com and place it before your route group which matches any subdomain.